# Return different value depends on times value

Tags: java, jmockit

There is code which calls method in the cycle, I want to test the case when the method throws exception in for 2 first attempts and then returns a valid value.
Using JMockit I write the following code:

```
new Expectations() {{
    someService.call(anyString);
    times = 2;
    result = exception;
    someService.call(anyString);
    result = entity;
}};
```

At this case it `someService::call` always returns `entity`.

How can I return an `exception` for first two calls and then return `entity` in test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like with any other mocking API, record each desired result of the expectation, in the desired sequence:

```
new Expectations() {{
    someService.call(anyString);
    result = exception;
    result = exception;
    result = entity;
}};
```

Answer (score 0):

[Try this](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.8.9/org/mockito/Mockito.html#10)

I think something like:

```
 Service someService = mock(Service.class);
 when(someService(any()))
   .thenThrow(new RuntimeException())
   .thenThrow(new RuntimeException())
   .thenReturn("foo");
```

should work

Comment: The question is about `JMockit` library

Comment: @BohdanKorinnyi please specify that in your question because it's understood as you just tried it but not restricted to it